# Adressing values of a nested structure in C

Tags: c, struct, nested

I have a nested structure as follows:

```
typedef struct {
   float mz_value;
   float int_value;
} spectrum;
typedef struct {
   // stuff
   spectrum* spectra; /* Nested struct */
   // more stuff
} chromatogram;
```

I allocate memory in my code as follows:

```
(chrom+i)->spectra=malloc(sizeof(spectrum)*1024);
```

I then want to assign some values to it and I have been trying all kinds of syntaxes similar to:

```
((chrom+i)->(spectra+j))->mz_value = (float)*(array_buffer+j);
// array_buffer is a float*
```

Yet this keeps giving me an error that I am failing at proper usages of braces, the only problem is that I can't figure out where o.O Any help would be greatly appreciated before I regret trying to use a nested structure.

Cheers,
Bas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
((chrom+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value = (float)*(array_buffer+j);
```

Or, preferably, use array notation, which is much clearer in this case:

```
chrom[i].spectra[j].mz_value = (float)array_buffer[j];
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks a lot, makes sense that the both structs should be in one set of braces instead of what I was doing with putting each struct in a set of braces :)

Answer (score 0):

Your spectra value is not a statically allocated structure it's a pointer
and you need allocate memory for it.

If you are going to work with fixed number of spectrum items
use statically allocated array

```
spectrum spectra[someConstantValue];
```

or allocate/free it dynamically, in this case you also need to hold number of elements.

```
typedef struct {
   // stuff
   spectrum* spectra; /* Nested struct */
   int count;
   // more stuff
} chromatogram;
```

Comment: I am assigning the memory to that in the second 'code' part. The amount of spectra is not fixed therefore the real code has a field int hits; in both structures which I did not show here. I also did not show the code where I free my memory as I felt that that was outside the scope of the question. Please do tell me if I misinterpreted your observations ;)